# Differences in power in regression versus mean of a ratio

Tags: regression, linear-model, ancova, statistical-power

I've been futzing around with the following example, and feel that there must be a good explanation or reference that I am blindly missing.

Supposer you have a linear relationship between two variables.  Let's even assume that the intercept goes through 0.  Why would there be more power in analysis by regression of y~x versus y/x ~ 1?  And in particular, if x is biased, the decrease in power is even more dramatic.  I can show this by simulation in the following R code, it strikes me that there is easy explanation here.

```
simBiasPower <- function(b=-1, ySD = 2, n=100, nsim=100){
  sapply(1:nsim, function(i) {
    unbiasedX <- runif(nsim, 0,10)
    biasedX <- rexp(nsim,0.5)

    unbiasedY <- rnorm(100, b*unbiasedX, ySD)
    biasedY <- rnorm(100, b*biasedX, ySD)


    return(c(unbiasedSlopeP= coef(summary(lm(unbiasedY ~ unbiasedX)))[2,4],
             unbiasedRatioP = coef(summary(lm(unbiasedY/unbiasedX ~ 1)))[1,4],
             biasedSlopeP = coef(summary(lm(biasedY ~ biasedX)))[2,4],
             biasedRatioP = coef(summary(lm(biasedY/biasedX ~ 1)))[1,4]
    ))  
  })

}

pMat <- as.data.frame(t(simBiasPower()))

library(plyr)
powerBySim <- colwise(function(acol) sum(acol<=0.05)/100)(pMat)

powerBySim
```

This produces the following estimates of power for the four analyses:

```
  unbiasedSlopeP unbiasedRatioP biasedSlopeP biasedRatioP
1              1           0.66            1         0.16
```

Note, I've tried this also forcing the intercept through 0 and thus not estimating an intercept for y~x, and the answer doesn't change. I've also changed the distributional form of the unbiased x, and it doesn't seem to matter very much.  Similar drop in power.

Of of the top of my head, when one divides by x, you reduce the leverage of points at the extreme end of the relationship - along the lines of reducing your variability in x in a regression context.  But it feels like there is something more forehead-smackingly basic going on here.

Comment: You are comparing two distinct models: the error structure in `y ~ x-1` and that in `y/x ~ 1` are very different.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the heart of the matter.  It's not a Cauchy, as y is dependent on x.  I feel like this might be getting at the heart of the matter.  That some property of the distribution of the ration is where I'm headed, but I'm unclear on what distribution is appropriate.

Comment: It's rarely a matter of what distribution is *appropriate*, but rather of what distribution actually pertains in any given problem. In some contexts a symmetrical distribution of errors for `y~x-1` may be appropriate while in others a symmetrical distribution for `y/x~1` may be suitable and in yet others something else is needed.

Comment: Indeed, very true.  Still, struggling to figure out how to connect this back to finding why there is such a drop in power.

Answer (score 1):

if Y and X are both normally distributed, Y/X follows the Cauchy distribution, (which has several strange properties... for example, the mean is not a measure of central tendency in this distribution... and the properties of the Cauchy distribution might be what is messing up the power in your regressions).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but, I thought that a Cauchy distribution was due to the ratio of two independent normal variables.  Here, y is dependent on x, so, this wouldn't quite be right.  But this seems like it's on the right track...

Comment: Neither: the Cauchy arises as the ratio of two *zero-mean* normal variates.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Gaussian_ratio_distribution.